# Element API - Filter on a value from a multi value field

Tags: plugin-elementapi

I am looking for some assistance with the Element API plugin. I need to filter on the `bannerPageCategories` field which is a multi select checkbox field. The value will be passed via a querystring value. I can filter on a field with a single value but how do I do this for fields which has an array of values.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Sample code and json response is below.

Json Response:

```
    {
      title:"Test Banner 4",
      url:"http://localhost:8888/banners/test-banner-4",
      jsonUrl:"http://localhost:8888/api/banners/17",
      content:"Test.", 
       page-categories:[
       {
         label:"ADSL",
         value:"adsl",
         selected:true
       },
       {
        label:"Fibre",
        value:"fibre",
        selected:true
       }
    ],
   campaignId:"sHKJJK",
   targetUrl:"http://xyx.xaws.co.za",
   image1:"//xyx.xaws.co.za/dev/images/banners/banner-lg.png",
   image2:"//xyx.xaws.co.za/dev/images/banners/banner-md.png",
   image3:"//xyx.xaws.co.za/dev/images/banners/banner-sm.png",
   date_published:"2018-05-22T14:06:05+02:00",
   date_modified:"2018-05-22T14:06:05+02:00"
  }
```

Code:

```
    'api/banners' => function () {
        \Craft::$app->response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $target = \Craft::$app->request->getQueryParam('target');
        $campaign = \Craft::$app->request->getQueryParam('campaign');
        return [
            'elementType' => Entry::class,
            'criteria' => [
                'section' => 'banners',
                'bannerPageCategories' => $target,
                'campaignId' => $campaign              
            ],
            'transformer' => function (Entry $entry) {
                $image1 = $entry->image1->first();
                $image2 = $entry->image2->first();
                $image3 = $entry->image3->first();

                return [
                    'title' => $entry->title,
                    'url' => $entry->url,
                    'jsonUrl' => UrlHelper::url("api/banners/{$entry->id}"),
                    'content' => $entry->htmlcontent,
                    'page-categories' => $entry->bannerPageCategories,
                    'campaignId' => $entry->campaignId,
                    'targetUrl' => $entry->targetUrl,
                    'image1' => $image1 ? $image1->url : null,
                    'image2' => $image2 ? $image2->url : null,
                    'image3' => $image3 ? $image3->url : null,
                    'date_published' => $entry->postDate->format(\DateTime::ATOM),
                    'date_modified' => $entry->dateUpdated->format(\DateTime::ATOM),
                ];
            },
        ];
    },
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you wrap your term in asterisks, e.g. `*news*`, the generated SQL for this query parameter uses a `LIKE` operator for the `ANDWHERE` condition is uses (see [Element Queries](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/element-queries.html#param-value-syntax)).

Make sure that the values for the Select field don’t overlap (`sportnews` and `news` both matching `*news*`).

```
'bannerPageCategories' => "*{$target}*"
```

Comment: Thanks @carics, much appreciated. I am still a noob with craft. Based on the combination of your answer and Robins answer I ended up using : 'bannerPageCategories' => ['=',  "*{$target}*"],.

Answer (score 1):

The value is stored as a serialized array in your database, in your case your would have to filter for the **string** `"["adsl","fibre"]"` (the order is the same like you specified in the field)

You can as well insert an array

```
['and',  '*adsl*', '*fibre*']
```

or

```
['or',  '*adsl*', '*fibre*']
```

Comment: Thanks Robin. I ended up going with 'bannerPageCategories' => ['=',  "*{$target}*"], which seemed to do the trick.